# How to keep client JSON web token secure in a React Native app?

Tags: security, token, react-native, json-web-token

We are building a React Native app for iOS and we are using an internal API built on node + express + jsonwebtoken.

When the user logs in with username/password, the server validates those credentials and sends the client back a JSON web token that they must then send along with every API request. So the React native app must store this token.

How do I securely store this client token in the React native app? Is it necessary to take any additional steps besides just storing the token in a variable?

Comment: To store sensitive information in React-native you can take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550361/7618742

Answer (score 9):

For iOS, you'd store that in the keychain...
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock-ios/save-and-refresh-jwt-tokens

Here's a couple ways of doing that in react native that I found. There may be others. There may be better options. This is just what I found quickly.

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=react-native+keychain

For Android, you'd store that in either the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or maybe even better the [KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/articles/keystore.html) since it's encrypted there.

Comment: Hi, any one please help me to find hood resource for JWT in react native.i think you guys using it , can any one share it please

Answer (score 7):

To be app agnostic, I would store it using [ASyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html). In fact I am testing this on a new project.

Comment: this isnt encryped though

Comment: Although AsyncStorage stores data [unencrypted](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#asyncstorage), depending on the security level you're after it could be an option. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39112472/747962

Answer (score 1):

I recently built a keychain manager in react-native so I may be able to help you.

NOTE: This solution does require that your app be running on expo.

To encrypt and store your tokens locally on the device you can use a package called [expo-secure-store](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/).

This will give you easy access to the iOS keychain and android keystore system and can be implemented as below:

```
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

/**
 * Saves the value to the ios keychain or Android keystore
 * @param {string} key => the key you want to save the value for
 * @param {any} value => the value you want to encrypt
 * @return => A promise that will reject if value cannot be stored on the device.
 */
SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);

/**
 * Fetches the value from the keychain/keystore for the specified key
 * @param {string} key => the key you set for the value
 * @returns {any} => A promise that resolves to the previously stored value, or null if there is no entry for the given key.
 * The promise will reject if an error occurred while retrieving the value.
 */
SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);

/**
 * Saves the value to the ios keychain or Android keystore
 * @param {string} key => the key you want to save the value for
 * @param {any} value => the value you want to encrypt
 * @return => A promise that will reject if value cannot be stored on the device.
 */
SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key);
```